# Filtering on iCalUId returns empty array

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Following query returns empty array
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=iCalUId eq '<iCalUId>'`

Response is

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('c4f741de-6d8c-4c28-97ca-8d00cef818aa')/events",
    "value": []
}
```

Passed `iCalUId` exist in `me/calender/calenderview`

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe post more details, like how you're getting the iCalUid and the exact request/response?

Comment: @JasonJohnston In our app we are already doing a `me/calender/calenderview` call i simply picked `iCalUId` from first value

Comment: I'm also not able to replicate this. I've tried on a number of tenants but it seems to reliably return the expected event.

Comment: @marc can what more info I need to provide for this. This is very critical issue for us

Comment: If this is a critical issue, I would recommend contacting Microsoft and opening a support ticket. It could be an issue with your particular tenant and that isn't something the community can help with.

Comment: Could it be that the event you are requesting is an instance of an event series?
In this case, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684521/filtering-on-icaluid-returns-empty-array-if-event-is-part-of-a-series) asks the same question. I tried it out, too: the /events endpoint does not give you results in that case. You could either use the id instead (which is different depending for different users) or the calendarView endpoint. However calendarView requires a startDateTime and endDateTime parameter.