# Filtering on iCalUId returns empty array if event is part of a series

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

My question is nearly identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176211/filtering-on-icaluid-returns-empty-array). I would have just commented over there but am unable to do so due to being a new user.

My request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=iCalUId eq '<iCalUId>'` returns the event object if I am querying a `singleInstance` event (this is expected). However, it appears that if the event is part of a series I get back an empty array.

I'm not sure if I am missing something or if this is expected behavior. I've scoured MS Graph docs (including [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) and [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter)) and have not been able to find a reason for this behavior.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue - in my opinion this is a bug in the Microsoft Graph API. I was able to work around this issue by using the [/calendarView](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) endpoint which does return events that are part of a series when searching by `iCalUId`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I considered this option, however, it gets tricky if the calendar event has moved outside the searchable window.